# Can't load admob native ads

Tags: android, admob, native, ads

When i try to load a native ad with a template this is the XML code i use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ededed">

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="320x150"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/native_ad_exit_app">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold"
       android:text="@string/sure_wanna_exit"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:padding="@dimen/half_activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="@color/standard_android_blue"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_size">

       <Button android:id="@+id/btnStayApp"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:text="@string/stay"
           android:textColor="#999999"/>

       <View
           android:layout_width="2dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/standard_android_blue"/>

       <Button android:id="@+id/btnExitApp"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:text="@string/exit"
           android:textColor="@color/standard_android_blue"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the java code:

```
public class NativeAdDialog extends DialogFragment {

    /**********************/
    /** Create the dialog**/
    /**********************/

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.native_ad_container, null);

        /********************/
        /** Exit app button */
        /********************/

        Button exitAppButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnExitApp);
        exitAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        /********************/
        /** Stay app button */
        /********************/

        Button stayAppButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnStayApp);
        stayAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        /***********/
        /** The ad */
        /***********/

        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(v).create();
    }

}
```

After it failed i tried to set a custom native ad like in this project:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExample

So i added the next code to my java file:

```
/**
     * Populates a {@link NativeAppInstallAdView} object with data from a given
     * {@link NativeAppInstallAd}.
     *
     * @param nativeAppInstallAd the object containing the ad's assets
     * @param adView             the view to be populated
     */
    private void populateAppInstallAdView(NativeAppInstallAd nativeAppInstallAd,
                                          NativeAppInstallAdView adView) {
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_headline));
        adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_image));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_app_icon));
        adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_price));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_stars));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_store));

        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every NativeAppInstallAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getBody());
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getCallToAction());
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(nativeAppInstallAd.getIcon()
                .getDrawable());

        List<NativeAd.Image> images = nativeAppInstallAd.getImages();

        if (images.size() > 0) {
            ((ImageView) adView.getImageView()).setImageDrawable(images.get(0).getDrawable());
        }

        // Some aren't guaranteed, however, and should be checked.
        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAppInstallAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAppInstallAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAppInstallAd);
    }

    /**
     * Populates a {@link NativeContentAdView} object with data from a given
     * {@link NativeContentAd}.
     */
    private void populateContentAdView(NativeContentAd nativeContentAd,
                                       NativeContentAdView adView) {
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_headline));
        adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_image));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_call_to_action));
        adView.setLogoView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_logo));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.contentad_advertiser));

        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every NativeContentAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getBody());
        ((TextView) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getCallToAction());
        ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeContentAd.getAdvertiser());

        List<NativeAd.Image> images = nativeContentAd.getImages();

        if (images.size() > 0) {
            ((ImageView) adView.getImageView()).setImageDrawable(images.get(0).getDrawable());
        }

        // Some aren't guaranteed, however, and should be checked.
        NativeAd.Image logoImage = nativeContentAd.getLogo();

        if (logoImage == null) {
            adView.getLogoView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) adView.getLogoView()).setImageDrawable(logoImage.getDrawable());
            adView.getLogoView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeContentAd);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a request for a new native ad based on the boolean parameters and calls the
     * corresponding "populate" method when one is successfully returned.
     */
    private void refreshAd() {

        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.native_ad_exit_app))
                .forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd appInstallAd) {
                        // Show the app install ad.
                        NativeAppInstallAdView adView = (NativeAppInstallAdView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.ad_app_install, null);
                        populateAppInstallAdView(appInstallAd, adView);
                        adPlaceholder.removeAllViews();
                        adPlaceholder.addView(adView);
                    }
                })
                .forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd contentAd) {
                        // Show the content ad.
                        NativeContentAdView adView = (NativeContentAdView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.ad_content, null);
                        populateContentAdView(contentAd, adView);
                        adPlaceholder.removeAllViews();
                        adPlaceholder.addView(adView);
                    }
                })
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, etc.
                    }

                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                        .build())
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}
```

I call refreshAd on onCreate method but adLoader.isLoading() always return false.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @SUXA have you found any solution for your problem?

Comment: No. I am using Interstitial ads instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ads:adSize="320x150" will work only with [small and medium template size native ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express#choosing_a_size)

A safer way to test would be to use ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx250" which supports  all three template sizes. FULL_WIDTH is not mandatory but I'm using it here to show you the possibilities. You may choose ads:adSize="280x250" instead to support all template sizes.

In AdMob when you create a new Ad Unit for Native Ads please make sure you select the right size as this is not modifiable in future. Allow several hours for AdMob to start serving Ads to the newly created Ad Unit Id.
Once you have everything working then you can change the size of the Ad to best match your design requirements.
[image: AdMob - Create a new AD Unit for native ad]

Comment: Finally someone found the problem. The size of my native ad is large and i used 320x150. FULL_WIDTHx250 also not working but 280x250 working great. Thank you very much. By the way, what is the best width and height for a large native ad?

Comment: There is no best size because it directly depends on your app. I mean in what size does it look best in your app. Considering the min and max restrictions in the template size choose wisely.